# Calculating partial derivatives of a rather difficult function

Tags: partial-derivative

> > How can I calculate the first partial derivative $P_{x_i}$ and the second partial derivative $P_{x_i x_i}$ of  function:
> >     $$
> > P(x,y):=\frac{1-\Vert x\rVert^2}{\Vert x-y\rVert^n}, x\in B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n,y\in S_1(0)?
> > $$

I ask this with regard to [Show that the Poisson kernel is harmonic as a function in x over $B_1(0)\setminus\left\{0\right\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568453/show-that-the-poisson-kernel-is-harmonic-as-a-function-in-x-over-b-10-setminu).

I think it makes sense to ask this in a separate question in order to give details to my calculations.

---

**First partial derivative:**

I use the quotient rule. To do so I set
$$
f(x,y):=1-\lVert x\rVert^2,~~~~~g(x,y)=\Vert x-y\rVert^n.
$$
Then I have to calculate
$$
\frac{f_{x_i}g-fg_{x_i}}{g^2}.
$$
Ok, I start with
$$
f_{x_i}=(1-\lVert x\rVert^2)_{x_i}=(1)_{x_i}-(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)_{x_i}=-2x_i.
$$
Next is to use the chain rule:
$$
g_{x_i}=((\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-y_i)^2)^{\frac{n}{2}})_{x_i}=\frac{n}{2}\lVert x-y\rVert^{n-2}(2x_i-2y_i)
$$

So all in all I get
$$
P_{x_i}=\frac{-2x_i\cdot\Vert x-y\rVert^n-(1-\lVert x\rVert^2)\cdot\frac{n}{2}\lVert x-y\rVert^{n-2}(2x_i-2y_i)}{\Vert x-y\rVert^{2n}}
$$

Is that correct? Can one simplify that?

I stop here. If you say it is correct I continue with calculatin $P_{x_i x_i}$.

Comment: Ok, but I remebered that. Where is the mistake? Where did I treat y as not constant?

Comment: Is the mistake at my calculation of $g_{x_i}$? I do not see where.

Comment: @math12 The inner derivative of $g_{x_i}$ is $2x_i$ and not $2x_i - 2y_i$

Comment: But why? The inner function is $\Vert x-y\rVert^2$, right? And if  I write this as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-y_i)^2$ then to my opinion the derivative is $2x_i-2y_i$?

Comment: In the second summand in the numerator of the last expression it must be $\;||x-y||^{n-1}\;$ , I think.

Comment: No, I think not. Because you have $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-y_i)^2)^{n/2-1}$ and this is the same as $\lVert x-y\rVert^{n-2}$, isn' it?

Comment: Right on! I missed that one...good!

Answer (score 0):

If $\;x=(x_1,...,x_n)\;,\;\;y=(y_1,...,y_n)\;$ , then

$$P(x,y):=\frac{1-\sum_{k=1}^nx_i^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{n/2}}$$

so for example

$$P_{x_i}'=\frac{-2{x_i}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{n/2}-n(x_i-y_i)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^{n/2-1}\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^nx_i^2\right)}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2\right)^n}$$

Comment: Could you please show me how you got the second summand in the numerator? The first is the same that I have but the second: I do not see how you get that.

Comment: Chain rule: the inner derivative$\;=2(x_i-y_i)\;$ multiplied by the exterior one$\;=\frac n2(\sum....)^{n/2 - 1}\;$ ...

Comment: So your result is exactly the same as my result. Great!

Comment: Now I have to calculate the derivative of this MONSTER. OMG

Comment: Yes, we have the same...and now *you* have to derivate that horror....good luck!

Comment: As the derivative of the numerator I got $-2\lVert x-y\rVert^n-n\lVert x-y\rVert^{n-2}(1-\lVert x\rVert^2)-n(x_i-y_i)(\frac{n}{2}-1)\lVert x-y\rVert^{n-4}(1-\lVert x\rVert^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

As the second derivative I get
$$
P_{x_i x_i}=-2\lVert x-\xi\rVert^{-n}+4x_in\lVert x-\xi\rVert^{-n-2}(x_i-\xi_i)-n\lVert x-\xi\rVert^{-n-2}(1-\lVert x\rVert^2)-n(x_i-\xi_i)^2(-n-2)\lVert x-\xi\rVert^{-n-4}(1-\lVert x\rVert^2)
$$

My question is if then

$$
\Delta P=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P_{x_i x_i}=0?
$$